# How to get UIBarButtonItem center position

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing some custom view controller transitions and I want my transition to start from the center of the button that was pressed.

For `UIButton` I can do:

```
myCustomTransition.startingPoint = buttonPressed.center
```

But if I want to use an `UIBarButtonItem`, how to actually tell my transition to start from the center of the button, because I don't see any `center` property on the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you need to place button at the center of nav bar, right ?

Comment: @vaibhav: no, my button is on the right hand side, I just need to know its position, but from what I am reading, there is no way to access the bounds of on UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: okay, if you opt just place a `UIView` at the center of nav bar and expand it to the end of right and left then proceed for get bounds.

Comment: Do you have  a swift 3 version of the code in the accepted answer?

Comment: @user2722667: I just removed the navigation bar, so I don't use the UIBarButtonItem anymore.

Comment: @Kobe did you not get it to work? - I guess u are using the bubble transition lib?

Comment: For me it didn't work, so I decided to just remove the all thing, and use a plain button. Yeah, I am using a circular transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use UIBarButtonItem as navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem or navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem, you can't directly get there geometry property, because UIBarButtonItem doesn't inherit UIView, but you eventually can get geometry property by using tricky method.

This is the hierachy of a simple ViewController that has left and right UIBarButtonItem:

[image]

**UINavigationButton** is your target, get its rect and you can get the center what you need.

```
- (void)handleItemPressed {
UIView *targetView = nil;
for (UIView *subView in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
        for (UILabel *label in subView.subviews) {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                if ([label.text isEqualToString:"right"]) {
                    targetView = subView;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

CGRect rect = [targetView convertRect:targetView.frame toView:self.view];
CGPoint center_you_need = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
}
```

If you use customeView,just convert customeView's frame to the point.