# How do I center the navigation items of a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I would like to center two navigation items so that they are aligned vertically with the navigation bar title view.

[image]

It was fairly simple to center the navigation bar title view of the navigation controller (this code belongs to a navigation controller custom class):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-8, for: .default)
}
```

But this code does not center the navigation items:

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
menuButton.tintColor = UIColor(r: 149, g: 156, b: 151)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

`UIButtonItem`s don't have a frame property, nor I can use auto layout. How can I center my navigation items?

Comment: Hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931976/how-to-get-uibarbuttonitem-center-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitlePositionAdjustment`?
Also you can try to use `imageInsets` property of your buttons.

Comment: Thanks. This code (positioned under `viewDidLoad()` of custom nav controller) is currently NOT changing the vertical position of the button items: `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -8), for: .default)`

Comment: `menuButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 12, right: 0)` DID work but I think it's a little bit tedious to set the imageInsets property for every bar button item in my app...

Comment: @cesare you can subclass UIBarButtonItem and do it once.